# Excel VBA type mismatch populating an array

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have  a range of varaible size that I store in an array. The type mismatch occurs when setting the array to the range values.

```
Dim arrA() as Variant
arrA = Range("rangeName").Value
```

I get a type Mismatch when it contains only one cell but it's fine when it has more cells.
I note than `typename(Range("rangeName").Value)` gives `String` when the range contains on cell and Variant() when it's more cells. 
Would like help to populate the array regardless of the size of the range.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: One cell is a special case.

Comment: That resolved it! Don't know how my research didn't turn that up. My first experience posting here and couldn't be happier. When the array was dimensioned automatically it was 2D and started at 1,1. So did the same when setting dimensions explicitly and all is good. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good stuff! Happy to help! Happy to hear it was a good experience - that isn't always the case and sometimes new users can get scared off.